# Is it possible to use USB port with a transmitter to control a robot

Tags: usb, wireless, robotics, mobile-robot

I have a project in mind that works as a robot accepting input from the computer through a male connector.

I have seen the circuits that use a wire system to connect to the robot. But is there any way to build a transmitter in the size of a USB modem and use it to transmit the signals.

Will it work or damage my laptop. Never tried connecting such wireless stuff to my laptop, so a bit nervous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could buy a really cheap USB bluetooth dongle like one of [these](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9434) from Sparkfun combined with a cheap serial to bluetooth module like [this](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8497) one. A wireless solution for ~ 30 dollars.

Comment: Thank you i must try the configurations using this device. And above all it is a less costly thingy.